# Difference in ReferenceError in a block scope and global scope if a let variable is used before initialization

Tags: javascript, scope, google-chrome-devtools, referenceerror

What's the reason for different `ReferenceError`s for these two snippets?

```
{
    console.log(a);
    let a;
}
```

ReferenceError: **Cannot access 'a' before initialization**

```
console.log(a);
let a;
```

ReferenceError: **a is not defined**

Same Errors are thrown if the variable is declared using `const a=5;`.

Also, errors vary depending on which side of the assignment operator a has been used.

```
a=5;
let a;
```

ReferenceError: **Cannot access 'a' before initialization**

```
var b=a;
let a;
```

ReferenceError: **a is not defined**

I read through the scope related docs on MDN but couldn't come up with an explanation.